# Enumerating unions of arithmetical sets

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

In Simpsons's excellent [Subsystems of Second-order Arithmetic](https://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa), we find V.4.10 which tells us the following:

*The following is provable in ATR$_0$.  Let $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of analytic codes. If $A_n$ is countable for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is countable*.

Note that 'countable' here means 'there is sequence of reals that includes all elements'. My question is whether this 'pushes down' to the arithmetical world, i.e. can we prove the following?

*The following is provable in ACA$_0$.  Let $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of **arithmetical** codes. If $A_n$ is countable for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is countable*.

Comment: I  don't have the definition of arithmetical code in front of me, but my first thought is that $0^{(n)}$ contains a $\Pi^0_2$-singleton.  Let that be $A_n$.  If you had a witnessing sequence for the countability of $\bigcup_n A_n$, it would bound all arithmetical sets and thus not be arithmetical, so wouldn't exist in the natural model of $\text{ACA}_0$.

Comment: Thanks for this counterexample and the ones I have received.